# How do I count the number of swaps (inversions) and comparisons in my merge sort code for my Linked List?

Tags: c++, mergesort

This is the code for my merge sort:
This is the merge function

```
node* Merge(node* h1, node* h2, int &comp, int &swaps){ node *t1 = new node; node *t2 = new node; node *temp = new node;


// Return if the first list is empty.
if(h1 == NULL)
    return h2;

// Return if the Second list is empty.
if(h2 == NULL)
    return h1;

t1 = h1;

// A loop to traverse the second list, to merge the nodes to h1 in sorted way.
while (h2 != NULL)
{
    // Taking head node of second list as t2.
    t2 = h2;

    // Shifting second list head to the next.
    h2 = h2->next;
    t2->next = NULL;

    // If the data value is lesser than the head of first list add that node at the beginning.
comp++;
    if(h1->data > t2->data)
    {
        t2->next = h1;
        h1 = t2;
        t1 = h1;
        continue;
    }

    // Traverse the first list.
    flag:
    if(t1->next == NULL)
    {
        t1->next = t2;
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    // Traverse first list until t2->data more than node's data.
    else if((t1->next)->data <= t2->data)
    {
        t1 = t1->next;
        goto flag;
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert the node as t2->data is lesser than the next node.
        temp = t1->next;
        t1->next = t2;
        t2->next = temp;
  
    }
}

// Return the head of new sorted list.
return h1;
```

}

This is the the merge sort function which calls on the merge function. I don't know if I should put the comparison and swap counters in merge or merge sort, and I don't know where in the function to put them.

```
void MergeSort(node **head, int &comp, int &swaps)
```

{

```
node *first = new node;
node *second = new node;
node *temp = new node;
first = *head;
temp = *head;




// Return if list have less than two nodes.
if(first == NULL || first->next == NULL)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    // Break the list into two half as first and second as head of list.
    while(first->next != NULL)
    {
        first = first->next;
        if(first->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
    second = temp->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
    first = *head;
}

// Implementing divide and conquer approach.
MergeSort(&first, comp, swaps);
MergeSort(&second, comp, swaps);

// Merge the two part of the list into a sorted one.      
*head = Merge(first, second, comp, swaps);
```

}

I'm not sure where to place my swap and comparison counters to count the number of swaps and comparisons that the merge sort makes?

Comment: I mean, after you swap or compare, right?

Comment: Well, mergesort doesn't really do swaps, so ...

Answer (score 0):

For the compares, you can increment a counter for each compare.

In the case of a bubble sort, the number of swaps is the same as the number of inversions, but merge sort does not do swaps, so what is wanted is the number of inversions.

Inversions are the number of occurrences where array[i] > array[j] and i < j, in an array. For example:

```
int InversionCount(int array[], int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (array[i] > array[j])
                count++;
    return count;
}
```

A typical merge step merges two already sorted sub-arrays, array[low to mid-1], array[mid to end-1]. Let i = index to left array (low to mid-1) and j = index to right array (mid to end-1). If during a merge you encounter a case where array[i] > array[j], then array[i to mid-1] will all be greater than array[j]. See if you can use this to determine and sum the number of inversions in the merge step part of a merge sort.

To do this for linked list based on the code in the question, make the following changes in order to keep track of the number of nodes in each sub-list:

```
node * MergeSortR(node *head, int count, int &comp, int &swaps);

node *MergeSort(node *head, int &comp, int &swaps)
{
    node * ptr = head;
    int count = 0;
    comp = 0;
    swaps = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        count++;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if(count < 2)
        return head;
    return MergeSortR(head, count, comp, swaps);
}

node * MergeSortR(node *first, int count, int &comp, int &swaps)
{
    if(count < 2)
        return first;
    node * second = first;
    int fstcnt = count/2;
    int sndcnt = count - fstcnt;
    for(int i = 1; i < fstcnt; i++)
        second = second->next;
    node *temp = second;
    second = second->next;
    temp->next = NULL;
    first = MergeSortR(first,  fstcnt, comp, swaps);
    second = MergeSortR(second, sndcnt, comp, swaps);
    return Merge(first, fstcnt, second, sndcnt, comp, swaps);
}
```

The worst case (reverse sorted elements) inversion count for n elements is n(n-1)/2. If using a signed  32 bit integer for the inversion count, the maximum list size is limited to 65536 to avoid any chance of overflow.

Comment: Well, I just need swaps, not necessarily inversions. But how would I implement that with how I have it set up as a linked list with nodes?

Comment: @SomethingYou - For a bubble sort, the number of swaps is the same as the number of inversions, but a merge sort doesn't do swaps, so what you want is the number of inversions.

Comment: @SomethingYou - I updated my answer to show how this could be done based on your code. See if you can figure out how to do the merge part.

Comment: Where am I supposed to increment the comp and swaps variables?

Comment: Nevemind, thank you

Comment: @SomethingYou - if you get stuck, I already have a working example for this.